# Docker: how to partion my harddrive

Tags: virtualization, partition, docker

I want to create partitions for my docker server.

It will only host stateful application, data are stored in /srv/company/appname.

I have two hard drive :

- 20GB
- 2TB.

What is the best way to create the partition ?

Is it: `20GB "/" , 2TB "/srv"`, or some other directories will grow with time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other directories should not grow to significant extent.  What you show seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Use something that lets you change the allocations later. ext4+lvm, btrfs or zfs.